# evacuation order in python condition expression

Tags: python, expression, conditional-statements

```
a=[]
b=[]
c= a[0],b if a else (None,None)
d= (a[0],b) if a else (None,None)
```

the first expression would raise IndexError ,but the second is fine.How does it happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line of code with the `IndexError` is evaluating the value of `a[0]` while the line after it is not.

For the line:

```
c= a[0],b if a else (None,None)
```

What is happening is the following:

Variable `c` is being assigned the value of `a[0]` and the value resulting from the `if` statement `b if a else (None,None)`.
To do this the line has to evaluate the value in `a[0]`.

---

For the line:

```
d= (a[0],b) if a else (None,None)
```

The value of `a[0]` is not yet being evaluated. Because the `if` statement doesn't reach the tuple that will try and evaluate the value in`a[0]`.

If you were to change the line to:

```
d= (a[0],b) if True else (None,None)
```

You would also get an `IndexError`

Comment: @WeiJianGuo You're welcome. If this answered your question please be sure to press the tick on the answer. It helps me, you and others.